# What exactly is the "presentation engine" in Vulkan jargon?

Tags: definition, vulkan

According to [this Khronos presentation](https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2016-vulkan-devday-uk/8-swapchains-unchained.pdf), a "presentation engine" is:

> The platform’s compositor or display engine

According to the [specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-khr-extensions/html/vkspec.html#_wsi_swapchain):

> The presentation engine is an abstraction for the platform’s compositor or display engine.
>
> The presentation engine may be synchronous or asynchronous with respect to the application and/or logical device.
>
> Some implementations may use the device’s graphics queue or dedicated presentation hardware to perform presentation.

Both these sources suggest that in most cases the presentation engine is a software entity ("abstraction") of the platform (which is itself, a software layer: the OS+window system).

Googling "window compositor display engine" provides me with this Wikipedia result, which seems relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager

Is that basically the article on "presentation engine"? For example, for Windows, the presentation engine would be Desktop Windows Manager, for a GNU/Linux system it could be Compiz, and so on? Or is it that the "presentation engine" is a combination the compositing manager and some other stuff?

Comment: Was the detailed answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/90ddad/what_exactly_is_a_presentation_engine_in_vulkan/) not sufficient?

Comment: I don't fully understand the nature of the question. The definition laid out in the Vulkan specification seems adequate to me. Are you asking what it is relative to some specific piece of hardware? I don't understand what you're trying to find out, exactly. It's an abstraction; how that abstraction gets implemented depends on the implementation.

Comment: @Jherico no, as both answers were speculative in nature, rather than definitive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Presentation engine* in Vulkan is an external component that manages and accepts the rendered image you made in Vulkan (assumably) for the purposes of presentation to the user.

From another POV, it is whatever the interface gives you. Which is `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`, `vkQueuePresentKHR`, etc., in the case of the `VK_KHR_swapchain` extension. Other extensions can be made, as presentation engines that operate fundamentally differently emerge (e.g. `VK_KHR_display_swapchain`).

`VK_KHR_swapchain`, requires `VK_KHR_surface`, which is specialized to `VK_KHR_win32_surface`, `VK_KHR_xlib_surface`, etc. So you can bet those are the APIs the driver talks to underneath. I.e. it talks to Win32 API (aka Windows API), probably to the GDI component (but possibly to the DXGI swapchain). On linuxes + `VK_KHR_xlib_surface`, it would talk to X server. And so on... which inevitably has to end up in the hands of the windowing manager such as the DWM or Compiz.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I found it helpful. A question I thought of recently: is it proper to think of the presentation engine as the "tip of the swap chain", in the sense that the swap chain is an abstraction, of which the presentation engine is the "final component"?

Comment: @user89 I get the feeling you want to see something more complicated here than it actually is. Maybe think of it as another `VkQueue`. There's graphics engine, compute engine, copy (transfer) engine, and presentation engine. Each can only process workload of its type, and Vulkan provides abstract API to feed these engines with work. To me, presentation engine is everything the API abstracts from the OS swap chain to the monitor. Swap chain being only the part that manages framebuffer handoff and release.

Comment: PS Vulkan is a specification, which is a special type of text document. It usually does not define terms it does not need. There's no "jargon" here. _Presentation engine_ is simply summary term for the *thing* that can accept your framebuffer and does whatever you expect it to do with it in the context of given (OS) platform. It is simply an abstract term for whatever can implement the API of the presentation commands, and Vulkan cares no more than this. Everything else is us extrapolating how it might, or might not work on given platform\OS, based on what we know about said OS.

Comment: +1 to it being an abstraction for "something that consumes a sequence of presented images". In some cases, the PE is literally the kernel display driver, when your application has exclusive ownership of the display or at least one of the display engine's overlay planes. Other times it is a system compositor (typical when windowed or non-exclusive fullscreen), e.g. DWM on Windows or SurfaceFlinger on Android. On some systems it might not even be a real display, e.g. on Android you can create a VkSurfaceKHR/VkSwapchainKHR from a ANativeWindow that sends images to a video encoder!